# Ruby on Rails exceptions from reserved keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I keep bumping into exception errors that I believe are due to conflicts from reserved keywords.

For example, I have a permit model with the attribute "gross_value" When my view tries to retrieve `@permit.gross_value` I get the following exception error. However, when I rename the attribute to `@permit.value_gross` (without changing anything else) the view works fine. I've had similar issues with other attribute names.

Is my diagnosis of the reason for the exception correct? How do I know what keywords to avoid this issue?

UPDATE: In the console when I try to access the attribute "total_weight" from the "permit" model e.g. "Permit.first.total_weight" I get a "stack level too deep" error message. When I rename the attribute from "total_weight" to "total_weigh" it works fine e.g. "Permit.first.total_weigh".

After renaming the attribute I still get the stack level too deep error message when trying to access "Permit.first.total_weight", which is curious because now the attribute does not exist so I expect to get a "undefined method" error as I do with other models e.g. "User.first.total_weight."

For now I am fine to make do with renaming my attribute to "total_weigh" - this has resolved the issue and everything is running smoothly. I'm just curious as to the reasoning and whether my diagnosis of a reserved keyword conflict is correct?

> fatal (exception reentered):

```
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:23:in `rescue in process_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionview (5.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Thanks for your help!

Simon

Comment: do you have some callbacks in your model?

Comment: I highly doubt that keywords is the cause here. Still trying to figure out what would your stacktrace mean

Comment: Could you show me the path you are trying to access when you get this error ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "permit model"? Would you post a "minimum non-working example" reproducing this error?

Comment: Hi all, "Permit" is the name of the model, my other models do not generate such exceptions even with the same attribute names. I did some more experiments in the console and renaming the attributes for the "Permit" model does seem to resolve the issue - see my updates in the description for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing any recursive calls in your code? This error usually means that you have re-entered a recursive call in your code.

Check your callbacks(i.e. `before_save`, `before_validation` etc.), if you have any, as these are common places where this can occur.

Comment: Hi grizzthedj, no callbacks in the "Permit" model. I did some more experiments in the console and renaming the attributes for the "Permit" model does seem to resolve the issue - see my updates in the description for reference.